# Question about eigenfunctions of a stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, probability-theory

Q) Why is it true that if $f$ and $g$ are eigenfunctions of a reversible Markov chain $P$ (i.e. $Pf = \lambda_i f,Pg = \lambda_j g$ and $f,g:\chi\to \mathbb{R}$) on the state space $\chi$ with stationary distribution $\pi$, and if $E_\pi (fg):=\sum_{x\in \chi}\pi(x)f(x)g(x)>0$, then $f$ and $g$ correspond to the same eigenvalue?

I can see that $E_\pi(f) = 0, E_\pi(g) = 0$ because:

$$\begin{align}
Pf &= \lambda f \tag{1} \\
\implies E_\pi (f) &= \pi Pf = \lambda E_{\pi}(f) \text{ By Multiplying $(1)$ by $\pi$ on the left} \\
\implies E_\pi (f) &= 0 \text{ when $\lambda\neq 1$}
\end{align}
$$

but not sure how to show the above?

Comment: What does it mean that $f$ and $g$ are eigenfunctions of $P$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Added detail to the question now.

Comment: What kind of MC are you considering and what is $\pi$?

Comment: This smells like an orthogonality argument, where $E_\pi[fg]=\langle f,g\rangle$. Since it can not be smaller zero, the above statement is equivalent to $\langle f,g\rangle \neq 0$ or in other words: f and g are not orthogonal. So it would be equivalent to show that the eigenspaces for different eigenvalues have to be orthogonal. Not sure how to show that statement for non-symmetric matrices though (it is false in general, so you would need to use that the matrix is stochastic)

Comment: Why would $E_\pi(f)=0$ be true? Aren't we talking about distributions?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Added detail to the question now.

Comment: @FelixB. I see, $P$ need not be symmetric in my case but is reversible, so I guess I need to use that to show eigenspaces for different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Comment: Could you explain why 
$E_\pi(f)=\pi Pf$ holds in your reasoning for $E_\pi(f)=0$? I assumed that the definition was $E_\pi(f):= \sum_x \pi(x) f(x)$

Comment: $E_\pi (f):= \sum_x \pi(x)f(x)$ is correct. $\pi$ is a row vector and $f$ a column vector. Thus $E_\pi(f) = \pi f$. $Pf = \lambda f \implies \pi Pf = \lambda \pi f \implies \pi f = \lambda \pi f \implies E_\pi (f) = \lambda E_\pi (f)$.